# Model method or custom template filter

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

My problem is that I need to know if a user has rated a certain model instance, BlogSite. On the page, there are multiple BlogSite instances, which have a 5-star rating system. When the current user has rated a certain instance, it should be set to read-only.

I'm running into a roadblock because if I use a model function, I need to pass 2 variables - current_user and BlogSite. I haven't been able to find how to access request.user in models.py and it's looking like I shouldn't be doing that?

The other path I went down was to create a custom filter - but I found out that I can only pass in one parameter. I would rather not do this method because I feel it would be better to keep the logic in views.py

Does anyone have ideas of how I can solve this problem?

```
#models.py
class BlogSite(models.Model):
    #fields

#get the average rating for a blogsite
def rating_avg(self):
    rating_dict = BlogSiteReview.objects.filter(blog_site=self).aggregate(Avg('review_rating'))
    rating_avg = rating_dict.get('review_rating__avg')
    if rating_avg:
        return rating_avg
    else:
        #no ratings
        return 0

def rated(self, current_user):
    #If there is a row for the blogsitereview with this blogsite for the logged in user, return True, else False
    #can I access the current user? This does not work, seems like I can't get request here.
    current_user = request.user
    review = BlogSiteReview.objects.filter(blog_site=self, user=current_user)

    if review:
        return True
    else:
        return False

class BlogSiteReview(models.Model):
    blog_site = models.ForeignKey(BlogSite)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    #other fields
```

Here is the relevant part of the view:

```
#views.py
def search(request, type, regionValue):
    #....
    #ideally, the solution would be to have a field or function in the BlogSite model
    blog_sites = BlogSite.objects.filter(country=region.id, active=True)
    #....
```

In the template I would have an if statement to add a class if rated returns True

```
<tr>
    <td><a href="http://{{ blogsite.url }}" id="{{ blogsite.id }}">{{ blogsite.site_name }}</a></td>
    <td><div id="rating{{ blogsite.id }}" class="rating {% if blogsite.user_rated %}jDisabled{% endif %}" data-average="{{ blogsite.rating_avg }}" data-id="{{ blogsite.id }}"></div></td>
    <td>{{ blogsite.create_date }}</td>
</tr>
```

I'm looking for 2 things here - does using a model method to get if a user has rated seem like the correct approach? The problem I have with this so far is that I can't find how to access the current user to use in models.py. Another idea I thought of is to pass in the request.current_user from the view somehow, but the user is not associated with BlogSite, so I can't filter on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up taking a slightly different approach which I thought of when trying to fall asleep but couldn't get Django out of my head :) In the view I created a list of blog_sites that a certain user left a review

```
#views.py
rated = BlogSiteReview.objects.filter(user=request.user).values_list('blog_site', flat=True)
return render(request, page, {..., 'blogsites':blog_sites, 'rated':rated})
```

And in the template I added a class if that blog_site FK id was in the blog_sites for loop:

```
#template
{% for blogsite in blogsites %}
<tr>
  <td><a href="http://{{ blogsite.url }}" id="{{ blogsite.id }}">{{ blogsite.site_name }}</a></td>
  <td><div id="rating{{ blogsite.id }}" class="rating {% if blogsite.id in rated %}jDisabled{% endif %}" data-average="{{ blogsite.rating_avg }}" data-id="{{ blogsite.id }}"></div></td>
  <td>{{ blogsite.create_date }}</td>
  <td>{{ rated }}</td>
</tr>
{% empty %}
  <p>There are no registered blogsites for this country.</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Finally I can go to sleep now!

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the result of `blog_site.rated(request.user)` via template parameters. If you feed your template with multiple BlogSite instances (`blog_sites` in your view sample) and iterate over them in the template, you could group the instance and the `rated` result into tuples or dicts in your view like so:

```
({"site": block_site, "rated": block_site.rated(request.user)} for block_site in block_sites)
```

And access these in the template with `result.site` and `result.rated`, respectively, assuming that `result` is the iteration variable (because you named your view `search`) in the template (replacing `blogsite` in your template snippet).

Hence, I personally would keep the `rated` method as you posted it, with the `current_user` parameter.

EDIT: here is an example which mixes your code (question and answer) and my proposal:

```
#views.py
def search(request, type, regionValue):
    #....
    blog_sites = BlogSite.objects.filter(country=region.id, active=True)
    search_results = ({"site": block_site, "rated": block_site.rated(request.user)} for block_site in block_sites)
    return render(request, page, {..., 'search_results': search_results})
```

And in the template:

```
{% for result in search_results %}
  {% with blogsite=result.site rated=result.rated %}
    <tr>
      <td><a href="http://{{ blogsite.url }}" id="{{ blogsite.id }}">{{ result.site.site_name }}</a></td>
      <td><div id="rating{{ blogsite.id }}" class="rating {% if rated %}jDisabled{% endif %}" data-average="{{ blogsite.rating_avg }}" data-id="{{ blogsite.id }}"></div></td>
      <td>{{ blogsite.create_date }}</td>
      <td>{{ rated }}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endwith %}
{% empty %}
  <p>There are no registered blogsites for this country.</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Just for completeness sake I added code examples based on your question and answer source codes to illustrate what I proposed to do. However, your approach (in your own answer) is probably more efficient, since it involves only one DB query to obtain rated blogsites instead of one query per blogsite via the rated method.